# XSLT, xsltproc parameters

Tags: xml, xslt

So, what I want to be able to do, is query an XML file using xsltproc, passing in a parameter for the NAME of the server.  This name is contained within the XML document.  I want to pull the username and password from this file.

So, the Name is a sibling of the User and Pass.  I don't use XSLT or XPath or XQuery all that often (this is the second time in 19 years now).  I'm just lost on how to pull the data from the XML file from the stylesheet.

Here's what I'm passing in from the CLI (I think it's right):
 `xsltproc --stringparam site_name "'site2'" style.xsl source.xml`

Here's the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Container>
    <Servers>
        <Folder expanded="1">
            <Server>
                <User>username1</User>
                <Pass>password1</Pass>
                <Name>Site1</Name>
            </Server>
            <Server>
                <User>username2</User>
                <Pass>password2</Pass>
                <Name>Site2</Name>
            </Server>
        </Folder>
        <Server>
            <User>username3</User>
            <Pass>password3</Pass>
            <Name>Site3</Name>
        </Server>
        <Server>
            <User>username4</User>
            <Pass>password4</Pass>
            <Name>Site4</Name>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</Container>
```

Here's my current XSLT Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="site_name">Site1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Servers">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Server/Name"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  Here's what I did, might not be the most efficient, but it seems to work.

The CLI usage was pretty much the same, I took out the single quotes.
`xsltproc --stringparam site_name "site2" style.xsl source.xml`

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="site_name">Site1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="Servers">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Server">
      <xsl:if test="Name=$site_name">
        <xsl:value-of select="User"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pass"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It also seems you don't have to use double quotes around the  string if it doesn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` attribute of the `xsl:value-of` in the `xsl:template` should use a path relative to the node that matched the `xsl:template`.

But really what you want is to change `xsl:value-of` to `xsl:apply-templates select="Server[Name=$site_name]"`. Then create `xsl:template match="Server"` that reports what you want to know about the server: its `User` and `Pass`.

Beyond this example, in case you would expect to have, say, thousands of servers, then you'd look into using `xsl:key`.

Comment: So how does that get the User and Pass from a matched Name?